# Verify contract not working (not match bytecode)

Tags: verify, mainnet

Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xec16fed4f619aacd70c7db48327d362f675bfc29

Contract.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract DogNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
    
    using Strings for uint256;
    
    mapping (uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdToPrice;

    string private _baseURIextended;

    
    constructor() ERC721("DogNFT", "DNFT") {}
        
    function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI_) external onlyOwner() {
        _baseURIextended = baseURI_;
    }
    
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token");
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }
    
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _baseURIextended;
    }
    
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory _tokenURI = _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        string memory base = _baseURI();
        
        if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
            return _tokenURI;
        }
        if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
        }
        return string(abi.encodePacked(base, tokenId.toString()));
    }
    
    function allowBuy(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) external {
        require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId), 'Not owner of this token');
        require(_price > 0, 'Price zero');
        tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = _price;
    }

    function disallowBuy(uint256 _tokenId) external {
        require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId), 'Not owner of this token');
        tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = 0;
    }

    function mint(
        address _to,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        string memory tokenURI_
    ) external onlyOwner() {
        _mint(_to, _tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(_tokenId, tokenURI_);
        tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = 0;
    }

    function buy(uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
        uint256 price = tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId];
        require(price > 0, 'This token is not for sale');
        require(msg.value == price, 'Incorrect value');
        
        address seller = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        safeTransferFrom(seller, msg.sender, _tokenId);
        tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = 0;
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

I tried using flatten and it removes duplicate licenses. I also changed the pragmas and kept only one in version 0.8.0. But he keeps making an error! (ps deploy by remix)

[image]

**EDIT**

Trying hardhat. Output:

`Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address 0xec16fed4f619aacd70c7db48327d362f675bfc29 has no bytecode. Is the contract deployed to this network? The selected network is mainnet.`

**EDIT 2**

**hardhat.config.js**

```
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.7",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  networks: {
      mainnet: {
        url: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxx`,
        accounts: {mnemonic: mnemonic}
      }
  },
  etherscan: { apiKey: "xxx" }
};
```

output:

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address provided as argument contains a contract, but its bytecode doesn't match any of your local contracts.

Possible causes are:
  - Contract code changed after the deployment was executed. This includes code for seemingly unrelated contracts.
  - A solidity file was added, moved, deleted or renamed after the deployment was executed. This includes files for seemingly unrelated contracts.
  - Solidity compiler settings were modified after the deployment was executed (like the optimizer, target EVM, etc.).
  - The given address is wrong.
  - The selected network (mainnet) is wrong.
```

Comment: try to create a new hardhat project, import your contracts and use the etherscan plugins, it will do it for you https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html

Comment: But my contract is deployed. I need deploy it again? @MajdTL

Comment: no you dont need to deploy it again, you will only compile and use the plugin to verify it

Comment: `Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format`

Comment: can you please post the command u used ? is it
npx hardhat verify  --network <your-network-name> 0xec16fed4f619aacd70c7db48327d362f675bfc29

Comment: I using `@nomiclabs/buidler` just for verify. Can I use the same settings of truffle in hardhat? I deployed my contract using remix

Comment: I will add a detailed answer at the weekend. Which solidity version has u had in remix and was optimisation enabled?

Comment: and which openZeppelin version has u used ?

Comment: version 0.8.0 ( because in my contract I used solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0; ). Using ERC-721 and Ownable.

Comment: u imported them in remix using @openzippelin or GitHub link?

Comment: Yes, using full url of master branch.

Comment: I forgot to flat before deploy..

Comment: Need to see the network config in hardhat.config.js

Comment: Don't flatten contracts. Use either [hardhat-etherscan](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/tree/d442b583b548ad9bc1192892b5374a90b15ec9f2/packages/hardhat-ethers) or [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Run `npm init -y` then `npm install --save-dev hardhat` after that open the folder in vsc and in the terminal run `npx hradhat` and choose `Create an advanced sample project`

Install Openzepplien `$ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`

In `hardhat.config.js` add the configuration for `mainnet` and the config of solidity to `0.8.0` (the same compiler version u used to deploy)

Add your contract in ./contracts , change the compiler version and run `npx hardhat compile`

In etherscan sign in and create an api key and copy that api key to your `hardhat.config.js`

> etherscan: { apiKey:  "your-api-key" }

and then run `npx hardhat verify --network mainnet 0xec16fed4f619aacd70c7db48327d362f675bfc29`

If this is not working then try to copy all related Openzeppelin contracts u used from github `main` to your `./contracts` and instead of import `@OpenZe...` use `./`

Comment: Question edited. Look to output when I try hardhat.

Comment: Show me please the config of ur network in hardhat.config.js? @GuilhermeIA

Comment: question edited again. now I got another error

Comment: @GuilhermeIA have u tried to copy the openZeppelin contract (for the commit on the day you deploy it) and add them directly to ur project. because I have no more ideas and I can’t sadly try myself on the mainnet. Have you deployed the contract using the same way that day on a Test net first?

Comment: using hardhat works perfectly, old question but works!

Answer (score -1):

Finally after 3 days - resolved

issue was with the compiler version!!.
Hope it helps someone out...